# Session breaks when use subdomains with dalli store in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session

I tried to use `:domain => :all` in `session_store.rb` and `config.action_controller.session = {:domain => '.mydomain.com'}` but anyway session breaks when i visit mydomain.com after www.mydmain.com.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this. I am having the same issue with devise logins and dalli?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SubdomainFu.configure do |config|
  config.tld_size = 2
  config.preferred_mirror = 'www'
end
```

Try with these configurable options. I hope it helps you.

Comment: That is not what i need. This gem "provides a single, simple solution for subdomain-based route and url management". And I have another issue. But thanks anyway

Comment: as i  understand perferred_mirror just redirects to www.domain.com from domain.com. This can be reached with web server configurationing. But I want to do it via rails configuration.